# Selenium AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'name' while fetching input

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, attributeerror

Not sure why this error is showing up, I've asked various questions relating to this issue already. Webdriver for some reason, just cannot find the type field i'm looking for, giving me Attribute not found errors as well as NoSuchElementException errors.

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.name,"nickname").send_keys(username+Keys.ENTER)
AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'name'
```

Line of code:

```
time.sleep(0.2)
driver.find_element(By.name,"nickname").send_keys(username+Keys.ENTER)
```

HTML:

```
<input name="nickname" type="text" placeholder="Nickname" maxlength="15" id="nickname" data-functional-selector="username-input" class="sc-gTgzIj eFnEAY" autocomplete="off" value="" aria-expanded="false">
```

Comment: I believe this line is case sensitive `By.name`. Use `By.NAME`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [The ***By*** implementation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) the set of supported locator strategies are:

- ***`CLASS_NAME`*** = *`class name`*
- ***`CSS_SELECTOR`*** = *`css selector`*
- ***`ID`*** = *`id`*
- ***`LINK_TEXT`*** = *`link text`*
- ***`NAME`*** = *`name`*
- ***`PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`*** = *`partial link text`*
- ***`TAG_NAME`*** = *`tag name`*
- ***`XPATH`*** = *`xpath`*

Accordingly, you have to change *`By.name`* as ***`By.NAME`***

Effectively, you line of code will be:

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME,"nickname").send_keys(username + Keys.ENTER)
```